# Passing parameters from my function into a calling function

Tags: javascript

I am passing a parameter that is a string and a number into a nested function bu I keep getting the following error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'  Here's the code:

I have tried different combinations of single and double quotes and I also tried without concatenation but it was all to no avail.

```
getData("Some list");

function buildTable(tblIDName, lstName, tblData){
    var id=3;
    var addTbl = document.querySelector("#myTbl");
    var newRow = addTbl.insertRow(1);
for (i=0; i<tblData.length; i++){
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' 
   onchange='update("+id+","+lstName+")' value='"+tblData[i]+"''>"; //<-Error points to this line
}
  }

function getData(listName){
  var tblData = ['col 1 data','col 2 data', 'col 3 data'];

  if (listName == 'Some list'){
    buildTable("#Benefits", listName, tblData)
  }else if (listName == 'Some Other List'){
    buildTable("#Assurance", listName)
 }
 }

function update(id,lst){
 alert(id);
 alert(lst);
}
```

When the onchange is triggered, I expect update() to execute.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/NexbEP?editors=0011

Comment: You need quotes around the value of `lstName`.

Comment: Even better, avoid inline handlers entirely, and attach the listener properly using Javascript's `addEventListener`

Comment: There are two single quotes in a row after `tblData[i]+"` in the line you highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try using something like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) that are both free source code editors. VS Code in particular can easily point out to you if a file has syntax errors before you even try to run it.

Having said that, the issue is in how you are trying to run update as an event to the cell input. Basically this requires a full replacement for that line where you are setting `cell.innerHTML`.

What you need is take this step-by-step by first creating an input element.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
```

With this created we can add the `value` attribute like so

```
input.setAttribute('value', tblData[i]);
```

Next you have to add an event handler when the input changes. Within that handler it will trigger the `update` function with and pass `id` and `lstName` as arguments.

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  update(id, lstName);
});
```

Finally we add this to the `cell`:

```
cell.appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did some clean up on the code, but primary problem was the string `some list` being passed in without being wrapped `"some list"`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Don't try and build anything until the DOM is ready.
  getData("Some list");
});



function buildTable(tblIDName, lstName, tblData) {
  let id = 3;
  let addTbl = document.querySelector(tblIDName);
  let newRow = addTbl.insertRow(0);
  
  tblData.forEach((td,i) => {
    cell = newRow.insertCell(i);
    // Note we needed to wrap string param correctly.
    cell.innerHTML = `<input type='text' 
    onchange='update(${id},"${lstName}");'
    value='${tblData[i]}'>`; 
    console.log(cell.innerHTML);
  });
}

function getData(listName) {
  let tblData = ['col 1 data', 'col 2 data', 'col 3 data'];

  if (listName == 'Some list') {
    buildTable("#Benefits", listName, tblData)
  } else if (listName == 'Some Other List') {
    buildTable("#Assurance", listName)
  }
}

function update(id, lst) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log(l);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTbl"></table>
<table id="Benefits"></table>
```